# How to apply css on text inside the text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-draggable

I am dragging tags from the dropdown list to a text-area but I want the tag's text as non-editable how I can achieve this.
You can see in the GIF that the text in Text-area is editable now.

```
//TextArea HTML Helper
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Formula, new { @class = "form-control", id = "total_selections", required = "required", rows = "4" })
//TextArea Dropable code
 $("#total_selections").droppable({
                hoverClass: 'active',
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var str = "";
                    debugger;
                this.value += $(ui.draggable).find('select option:selected').append(',').text();
                str = this.value;
                $("#total_selections").text(str);
                }

            });
```

[image]

Comment: you can disable total_selections , add disabled to the text area in your HTML, i think it should work  ```<textarea disabled></textarea>```

Comment: @Elnatanvazana i don't want to make the whole text-area disable i just want to make text disable.

Answer (score 0):

the solution can be to prevent the keypress event on the textarea.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
let textarea = document.getElementById('textarea')

textarea.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

codepen; https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/QWNwaZR

this should do the trick.